# How to do use C-x k to kill an Emacs buffer opened in server mode?

Tags: emacs

I use windows batch file to open files in an already-running instance of Emacs using emacsclientw.exe.  However, any file opened that way is opened in server mode, which means that I have to use C-x # to kill it, instead of the usual C-x k.  How do I change this behavior?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268088/, which has more answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use:

```
D:\> emacsclientw -n foo.txt
```

the -n says "no wait".  This is in GNU Emacs 22.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2008-03-26 on RELEASE (and many prior versions, IIRC).

Comment: hrm - can't get that to work with the FireFox "It's all Text" plugin. "Can't find path <blah blah -n" -- same results under various permutations with trailing space and enclosing in quotes. BUT the question-at-hand is for batch-files. so.

Comment: I use It's All Text, too, and just have D:\product\emacs\bin\emacsclientw.exe in it.  I don't have a problem killing buffers visited using IAT.  I can't remember ever changing kill-buffer to accomodate this (and a quick check through my .emacs confirms this).

Answer (score 7):

My solution was to rebind it (well M-w actually) to:

```
(lambda ()
  (interactive)
  (if server-buffer-clients
      (server-edit)
    (kill-this-buffer)))
```

[edit: having now read the code for server-edit, it might be better to use server-done (depending on what you want).  server-edit will switch you to a server-edited buffer (if any still exist) but server-done will simply switch you to the next buffer.  You could also use the output of server-done to see if the buffer was actually killed (not the case if the file was open before invoking emacsclient) and then kill it if not.  Or use server-kill-buffer as suggested elsewhere.]

Comment: This will break things horribly.  `server-edit` will switch to a server buffer if you are not currently in one, which means you can only kill buffers if you've killed all server buffers.  (Also, M-w is a pretty important binding, you never use it?)

Comment: server-buffer-clients is only non-nil if I'm editing if I'm already in a buffer being waited on by a client, unless the documentation is wrong.  And no, I don't use kill-ring-save bound to M-w.  I must admit I probably rebind too many keys, but...

Comment: OK, you're right.  I would use server-kill-buffer instead of server-edit though.

Comment: I stopped using CUA mode early on -- M-w, FTW. \n using (server-kill-buffer) in the above function (bound to (kbd "C-x k") requires me to enter C-x k TWICE. ???

Answer (score 7):

Here is what i put in my .emacs to do this :

```
(add-hook 'server-switch-hook 
  (lambda ()
    (local-set-key (kbd "C-x k") '(lambda ()
                                    (interactive)
                                    (if server-buffer-clients
                                        (server-edit)
                                      (ido-kill-buffer))))))
```

Like this C-x k work the usual way when i'm not finding a file from emacsclient (which for me is ido-kill-buffer), and if i'm using emacsclient, C-x k does server-edit if the client is waiting, or run ido-kill-buffer otherwise (if i used emacsclient -n).

Comment: Oh, nice! Works like a charm, and removes that whole rebinding issue!

Answer (score 4):

You know, I hate to suggest workarounds instead of a real solution... but after reading the server code, I am confused as to how emacs even determines that a buffer is a server buffer.

With that in mind, why not open up files like:

```
emacsclient --eval '(find-file "/path/to/file")'
```

This way emacs doesn't know that your buffer was opened via emacsclient, which sounds like what you really want.

Edit:

I'm not really happy with this, but it seems to work:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x k") (lambda () (interactive) (server-kill-buffer (current-buffer))))
```

Comment: I get a Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments #[nil " <etc etc etc>

I'm running GNU Emacs 23.0.60.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2008-08-19 on LENNART-69DE564 (patched)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, THIS did work for me:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x k") '(lambda ()
  (interactive)
  (if server-buffer-clients
      (server-done)
    (kill-this-buffer))))
```

(this is the code from IvanAndrus's answer with the explicit changes from edits and comments, and using jrockway's keybinding.)

And, yes -- I am rebinding a standard keybinding. BUT it's a functional replacement NOT something completely different (eg, replacing kill-ring-save with kill-buffer stuff).

BTW, EmacsWiki has a couple of pages on this topic--  [KillKey](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/KillKey) and [KillingBuffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KillingBuffers) -- neither of which shed better light for me than the above (although the first-function on KillKey also used "server-edit"...).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that will work on windows, but on linux, emacs -daemon is just great. 
With it, you don't have to run a different program, and your bindings are the same. I guess there are other advantages, but since I could never learn those emacsclient bindings, I never really used it, and can't say.

I don't think -daemon had been released yet, I am using 23.0.60.1 from CVS.